# Copy products to customer order notes

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hey we're using fullfilment company and need to include Yith Product Addons product options in customer order note. Following code works but doesn't insert product options (idk if that should be item meta or variations). So if we have a gift box, customer can choose t-shirt, color and customization and that won't display in that note. It only displays product name and quantity.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'products_in_customer_notes', 10, 2 );

function products_in_customer_notes( $order_id, $order ) {
    
    // Verify it's a WC Order
    if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
        $customer_note = $order->get_customer_note();

          foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
              $product_name = $item->get_name();
              $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
              $customer_note .= "<br>";
              $customer_note .= $quantity . 'x ' . $product_name;
          }

        // Add the note
        $order->set_customer_note($customer_note);

        // Save the data
        $order->save();
    }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve that?

I've tried to add

```
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product_name = $item->get_name();
            $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();
            **$metadata     = $item->get_meta_data(); // Get item metadata**

            $customer_note .= "<br>";
            $customer_note .= $quantity . 'x ' . $product_name;
```

but it didn't help.

Comment: First you need to check in `wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table to search for this add-on data… Once you find it, use the related meta_key(s) in something like: `$customer_note .= "<br>" . $item->get_meta('meta_key');` *(replacing `meta_key` with the real meta_key found in the database)*...